# How to track output when running a background process in a jupyter notebook using Ipython magic

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, python-asyncio, ipython-magic

I am trying to make use of the magic command `%%bash --bg` to run multiple bash commmands in the background asynchronously from a jupyter notebook session(note `%%bash` is an alias for `%%script bash`). I am doing this under the assumption that it will allow me to send subprocesses to different cpus. As a reduced example:

```
%%bash --bg --out out_variable --proc popen_instance
ls
```

Has the argumnts `--out` and `--proc` which return objects to the stdout and the popen instance as explained in the [IPython documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-script). When printing the variables in the next cells `popen_instance` prints:

```
<_AsyncIOProxy(<Process 1203497>)>
```

And `out_variable` outputs:

```
<_AsyncIOProxy(<StreamReader 453 bytes eof transport=<_UnixReadPipeTransport closed fd=64 closed>>)>
```

How can I use these to variable to track the progress of the background command that I have sent? The ideal for me would be for the ouput to be logged into a text file so I could open it up. And check how it is doing.

Reading around I found that using `await out_variable.read()` would work to check my output but as the name implies only after the subprocess has finished. I am intersted in tracking the progress of the process on the run.